# Entity framework generates ORDER BY statements for tables with Guid as PK

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, azure-sql-database, guid

We have the following situation:

- SQL Azure
- Entity framework 6.1.1
- Tables that have Guid's as PK and a specific "hidden" Int "SysID" as clustered index that is required by SQL Azure

When entity framework translates our LINQ expressions to SQL, we get huge ORDER BY statements at the end of the query. Is this because EF is confused with the PK not being the clustered index, and thus explicitely defining "some" ordering, as we're not projecting out the SysID in our queries?

Anyone else noticed these generated ORDER BY statements?

Comment: What's the linq look like?

Comment: It usually happens when you use collection `Include` in the query.